# Split Mini USB No MINI port on Computer

Tags: usb-2

I am attempting to connect my new c.crane my Super USB WIFI 3 antenna to boost my signal so my neighbor can connect to our router.. It came with a USB splitter one side of which is a MINI USB.. Instructions indicate to plug both in to boost the signal.. My laptop does not have a MINI USB port..   Can I run a regular split USB cable instead of the Mini/USB split...  I have several of those.

Comment: I don't understand. What's the relationship between this antenna, a "mini/USB split" (what is that?) and USB in the first place? Please [edit] your question to clarify it, perhaps even mentioning the specific product you are trying to get to work, and we'll be much more likely to be able to help you.

Comment: Not asked, but please realise that boosting your signal is only part of what is needed. It is like giving 1 person in a conversation a bullhorn. Unless you also give one to the other person that will still not allow long distance conversations.  (aka you neighbour will also need to boost his signal).

Answer (score 0):

#### It came with a USB splitter one side of which is a MINI USB

The cable is a USB Y-Cable. See my answer to [Weird USB cable (usage?)](https://superuser.com/a/936376/337631) for more information about USB Y-Cables.

[image]

> **Why are there two USB input connectors on this antenna cable? If I can only use one on my computer which one do I use?**
>
> One USB connector is for power and data transfer, the other is for a boost to power. You will want to use the power and data USB connector which is the one with two cables attached to it.

The split end of the cable has two normal USB connectors, both of which should be plugged into your PC.

The other end is a micro USB connector, this end plugs into the antenna.

Source [FAQs](http://www.ccrane.com/Super-USB-WiFi-Antenna-3-High-Power-Long-Range-80211-B-G-N-Wireless-1)